# Problem with DataFrame (list is read as string)

Tags: python, dataframe

I can't solve this problem, I'm trying to make my DataFrame show the data in five columns and l2 rows. However, it keeps giving me everything in one row. As you can see, I'm trying to use the lists generated from the random functions, but I think it reads the list as a single string.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
nomes = ['João', 'Maria', 'Pedro', 'Pablo', 'Vitor', 'Rogério', 'Marcelo', 'Farias', 'Júlia', 'Diego', 'Rafael', 'Marcos', 'Sofia', 'Kleber', 'David', 'Paulo', 'Rosane', 'Roberta', 'Beatriz', 'Júlio', 'Camile', 'Antônio', 'Otávio']
alunos = random.sample(nomes, 12)
notas_1_trimestre = np.random.randint(0,10,12)
notas_2_trimestre = np.random.randint(0,10,12)
notas_3_trimestre = np.random.randint(0,10,12)
notas_4_trimestre = np.random.randint(0,10,12)
data = {'Alunos': [alunos], 'Notas_1_trimestre':[notas_1_trimestre], 'Notas_2_trimestre':[notas_2_trimestre], 'Notas_3_trimestre':[notas_3_trimestre], 'Notas_4_trimestre':[notas_4_trimestre]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: In your data assignment don't enclose each numpy array in a list just use `data = {'Alunos': alunos, 'Notas_1_trimestre':notas_1_trimestre, 'Notas_2_trimestre':notas_2_trimestre, 'Notas_3_trimestre':notas_3_trimestre, 'Notas_4_trimestre':notas_4_trimestre}`

Comment: It worked, but in the column 'Notas_2_trimestre' everythin is replaced by a '...'

Comment: Sounds like its not displaying all the columns due to your display area.  To get it to show all columns add this line before the print statement: `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)`

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and the column is being shown as the others, but it's below the other columns. Do you know if I could extend the columns so each one would be side by side (including the last one, which is being displayed below the first)?

Comment: To get all the data in a signal line fashion try: `pd.options.display.width=None`  You can also use the [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) module to display dataframes in varous formats.

Comment: I see. I actually tried to use pd.set_option('display.max_columns', ) and pd.set_option('display.width', ) and it fixed my problem, but thank you very much for the tips bro

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting lists in lists. You should pass the lists directly as values in the dictionary, ie remove the brackets.

```
data = {
    'Alunos': alunos,
    'Notas_1_trimestre': notas_1_trimestre,
    'Notas_2_trimestre': notas_2_trimestre,
    'Notas_3_trimestre': notas_3_trimestre,
    'Notas_4_trimestre': notas_4_trimestre
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I see, it worked well, but in the column where it's supposed to be 'Notas_2_trimestre', I'm getting a lot of '...' elements. You know how to fix it?